# The colormap is not correct for logical heatmaps

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, colormap

I wanted to plot many binary heatmaps. Most of them have both 0 and 1 entries but few of them have complete 0 or 1. In those cases the heatmaps are not showing correct.  In the following example subplot 3 and 4 colormap is not correct. Is there anyway to select colormap automatically based on logical True/False value? Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib import gridspec

import numpy as np
import seaborn as snn
import random 
M=np.zeros((2,5))
for j in range(2):
    for i in range(5):
        r=random.random()
        M[j,i]=r

print(M)
#[[0.61060519 0.04500793 0.74199826 0.22084509 0.31493589]
#[0.3432519  0.59293327 0.50043671 0.07201856 0.65329049]]
M0=M>0.5
M1=M>0
M2=M>2

M0 = M0.astype(float)
M1 = M1.astype(float)
M2 = M2.astype(float)


fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=1, nrows=4, height_ratios=[1,1, 1,1])
ax0=fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[3])

colors = ((1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1, 0.0, 1.0))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))


b=snn.heatmap(M,ax=ax0)

b=snn.heatmap(M0,cmap=cmap,ax=ax1)
colorbar = b.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '1'])


b=snn.heatmap(M1,cmap=cmap,ax=ax2)
colorbar = b.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '1'])



b=snn.heatmap(M2,cmap=cmap,ax=ax3)
colorbar = b.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '1'])



fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('a.png',dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

[image]

I edited my code now and it seems it is working what I wanted. But you have better suggestion please let me know.

```
M0=M>0.5
M1=M>0
M2=M>2
M0 = M0.astype(float)
M1 = M1.astype(float)
M2 = M2.astype(float)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=1, nrows=4, height_ratios=[1,1, 1,1])
ax0=fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs[3])    

def chooseColorBar(ax,M):
    if np.mean(M)==0:
        colors = ((1.0, 1.0, 0.0),(1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
        cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))
        b=snn.heatmap(M,cmap=cmap,ax=ax)
        colorbar=b.collections[0].colorbar
        colorbar.set_ticks([0])
        colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0'])
    elif np.mean(M)==1:
        colors = ((1, 0.0, 1.0),(1, 0.0, 1.0))
        cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))
        b=snn.heatmap(M,cmap=cmap,ax=ax)
        colorbar=b.collections[0].colorbar
        colorbar.set_ticks([1])
        colorbar.set_ticklabels(['1'])
    else:
        colors = ((1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1, 0.0, 1.0))
        cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))
        b=snn.heatmap(M,cmap=cmap,ax=ax)
        colorbar=b.collections[0].colorbar
        colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
        colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '1'])

b=snn.heatmap(M,ax=ax0)
chooseColorBar(ax1,M0)
chooseColorBar(ax2,M1)
chooseColorBar(ax3,M2)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('a.png',dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like seaborn doesn't like boolean entries. When you make `M1 > 0`, etc., that gives you a boolean array. When are the entries are True or False, there is some problems. You can convert it to float and it will work. So, after you create M0/1/2, add these lines..

```
M0 = M0.astype(float)
M1 = M1.astype(float)
M2 = M2.astype(float)
```

This will give you the right plot. Tried with all True, all False, etc. Appears to be working fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. On your suggestion I add astype lines but colorbar is still wrong.

Comment: Is the attached plot what you are expecting? I am using jupyter notebook on windows with python 3.8.8, seaborn 0.11.1, matplotlib 3.3.4 and numpy 1.20.1. Wondering if it is env or version issue

Comment: Yes attached down plot I am expecting. It is not related to version issue. I changed M2=M>2.